# Detection of contradictions

Tags: optimization, rdbms

I found some old notes of mine from 2011 and I also re-read the excellent article [10 Cool SQL Optimisations That do not Depend on the Cost Model](https://blog.jooq.org/2017/09/28/10-cool-sql-optimisations-that-do-not-depend-on-the-cost-model/) by @lukas-eder. So I thought I would take my notes for another spin. The scenario is quite simple [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=26f405e91312408cd9723c2d3e89ec0e)

```
create table emp ( 
    emp_no int not null primary key, 
    title varchar(10) not null, 
    salary int not null, 
        check (emp_no > 0), 
        check (title in ('BOSS','WORK'))
);

insert into emp with recursive t (n) as (
    values (1) 
    union all 
    select n+1 from t where n+1 < 1000
) select n, case when mod(n,10) = 0 then 'BOSS' else 'WORK' end, 
            case when mod(n,10) = 0 then 110 else 0 end + mod(n,90) 
from t;
```

Now, given the rules:

```
 (TITLE = BOSS) implies (SALARY > 100)
```

and

```
 (TITLE = WORK) implies (SALARY <= 100)
```

which can be implemented as:

```
-- (TITLE = BOSS) => (SALARY > 100)
alter table emp add constraint cc1 
    CHECK ( (title <> 'BOSS' OR salary > 100) );
-- (TITLE = WORK) => (SALARY <= 100)
alter table emp add constraint cc2
    CHECK ( (title <> 'WORK' OR salary <= 100) );
```

and the query:

```
select * 
from emp 
where title = 'BOSS' and salary <= 100
```

can the DBMS spot the contradiction, and return an empty result set without even touching the data?

```
Let A = ( title = ’BOSS’ ), B = ( salary > 100 )

select * from emp where (A ^ ~B)                    
select * from emp where (A ^ ~B) ^ (~A v B)           # by cc1 
select * from emp where (A ^ ~B ^ ~A) v (A ^ ~B ^ B)    
select * from emp where (FALSE ^ ~B) v (A ^ FALSE)      
select * from emp where (FALSE) v (FALSE)           
select * from emp where (FALSE)
```

I have tried Postgres 13 (see fiddle above)

```
Seq Scan on emp  (cost=0.00..26.50 rows=2 width=46) (actual time=0.134..0.134 rows=0 loops=1)
  Filter: ((salary <= 100) AND ((title)::text = 'BOSS'::text))
  Rows Removed by Filter: 999
Planning Time: 0.312 ms
Execution Time: 0.149 ms
```

and Db2 11.5.4.0:

```
Optimized Statement:
-------------------
SELECT 
  Q1.EMP_NO AS "EMP_NO",
  Q1.TITLE AS "TITLE",
  Q1.SALARY AS "SALARY" 
FROM 
  DB2INST1.EMP AS Q1 
WHERE 
  (Q1.SALARY <= 100) AND 
  (Q1.TITLE = 'BOSS')

Access Plan:
-----------
        Total Cost:             51.8267
        Query Degree:           1


      Rows 
     RETURN
     (   1)
      Cost 
       I/O 
       |
     90.2441 
     TBSCAN
     (   2)
     51.8267 
        4 
       |
       999 
 TABLE: DB2INST1
       EMP
       Q1
```

but both fail to do so. Any other DBMS that can spot the contradiction and act upon it? This is of course more of an amusement than a real-world problem, but still.

Edit: The constraint suggested by @federico-razzoli in his answer does not work either:

```
alter table emp add constraint cc1
    check ((title = 'BOSS' and salary > 100) or 
           (title = 'WORK' AND salary <= 100));
```

and the same query still causes table-access

```
 Rows 
 RETURN
 (   1)
  Cost 
   I/O 
   |
 90.2441 
 TBSCAN
 (   2)
 51.8267 
    4 
   |
   999
```

TABLE: DB2INST1
EMP
Q1

Comment: This question has understandably generated a fair amount of chat in comments. Chat is a better venue for that so they have been **[moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115646/discussion-on-question-by-lennart-detection-of-contradictions)**. Please discuss the question there and reserve comments for question improvement ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a summary of how a number of DBMS handles the constraints in the question. 3 other queries are also tested:

```
1.  select * 
    from emp 
    where title = 'BOSS' and salary <= 100

2.  select * 
    from emp 
    where title = 'BOSS' and salary <= 100 
      and False

3.  select * 
    from emp 
    where title = 'BOSS' and salary <= 100 
      and ( NOT (title = 'BOSS' AND salary <= 100) )

4. select *  
   from emp 
   where title = 'BOSS' and salary <= 100 
     and ( (title <> 'BOSS' OR salary > 100) )
```

**Db2 V11.5.4.0**

Fails to identify contradiction in q1, succeeds for q2, q3, q4

```
db2 "explain plan for select ..."
db2exfmt -d nya -1
[...]
```

1. 

```
Access Plan:

-----------
Total Cost:             51.8267
Query Degree:           1


  Rows 
 RETURN
 (   1)
  Cost 
   I/O 
   |
 90.2441 
 TBSCAN
 (   2)
 51.8267 
    4 
   |
   999 
TABLE: DB2INST1
   EMP
   Q1
```

2,3,4.

```
Optimized Statement:
-------------------
SELECT 
  NULL AS "EMP_NO",
  NULL AS "TITLE",
  NULL AS "SALARY" 
FROM 
  (VALUES
  ) AS Q1 
WHERE 
  (FALSE = TRUE)

Access Plan:
-----------
    Total Cost:             7.58112e-05
    Query Degree:           1


   Rows 
  RETURN
  (   1)
   Cost 
    I/O 
    |
     0 
  TBSCAN
  (   2)
1.27533e-05 
     0 
    |
     0 
TABFNC: SYSIBM  
  GENROW
```

**MariaDB 10.5**

Fails to identify contradiction in query 1,3,4, succeeds for query 2

[Fiddle MariaDB](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=9aea30b374cdd1b576bc3f5b500200dc)

1,3,4.

```
    Extra
    Using where
```

2. ```
    Extra
    Impossible WHERE
   ```

**MySQL 8.0**

Fails to identify contradiction in query 1,3,4, succeeds for query 2

[Fiddle MySQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&sample=sakila&fiddle=9aea30b374cdd1b576bc3f5b500200dc)

1,3,4.

```
    Extra
    Using where
```

2. ```
    Extra
    Impossible WHERE
   ```

**Oracle 18c**

Not 100% sure how to interpret the plan, but it says TABLE ACCESS Full for all 4 queries so I guess it means it failed 1,2,3,4

[Fiddle Oracle 18c](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c0e3746ace15694ac79a7f5eb6e43395)

**Postgres 13**

Fails to identify contradiction in q1, q3, q4, succeeds for q2

1,3,4.
QUERY PLAN
Seq Scan on emp  (cost=0.00..26.50 rows=2 width=46)
Filter: ( ...

2.
QUERY PLAN
Result  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=0 width=0)
One-Time Filter: false

[Fiddle Postgres](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0be119919e30c1c42a9add7be19933fa)

**SQL-Server 2019**

Fails to identify contradiction in q1, q3, q4, succeeds for q2

[Fiddle SQL-server](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&sample=adventureworks&fiddle=316184eefd63579547f496f4ab799a4c)

**Conclusion**

None of the tested DBMS succeeded to use the information from the constraints.

Db2 is the only one that uses the information if it is injected into the query.

As it seam, Oracle is the only one that fails for all 4 queries.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is great, but it skips one step. You are assuming that the query planner (or optimiser, depending which terminology you prefer) can keep into account all CHECKs, merging them.

So you have:

```
check (title in ('BOSS','WORK'))
```

And:

```
CHECK ( (title <> 'BOSS' OR salary > 100) )
CHECK ( (title <> 'WORK' OR salary <= 100) )
```

And you assume that the planner should be able to know that:

```
CHECK ((title = 'BOSS' and salary > 100) or title = 'WORK' AND salary <= 100)
```

This could be the case or not.

In general, the question to your answer depends on the technology you are using. MySQL and MariaDB don't take into account CHECKs. Some other technologies probably do. You'll have to test the technologies you are interested in.

Comment: I'm curious whether there is a RDBMS that is capable of deducing the contradiction. I have looked at Db2 11.5 which can handle a lot of similar but less complicated situations (does not detect this). I also checked PostgresSQL 13 which did not detect it either (and much to my surprise does not seem to care much about check constraints in this regard). Since I don't have access to the latest, greatest products from all vendors I asked the question here in case someone wanted to test their favourite RDBMS and report back the result.

Comment: Unless you have already read it, the article by Lukas Eder: https://blog.jooq.org/2017/09/28/10-cool-sql-optimisations-that-do-not-depend-on-the-cost-model/ compares how well different products handles query rewrites in other but similar regards

Comment: Thank you @Lennart. With Db2, did you only try the original CHECKs (which require validating the conditions against a *combination* of two checks), or also the CHECK I suggested in my answer? I'd expect it to properly detect the anomaly with "my" constraint. I am not too surprised that PostgreSQL does not care about CHECKs, because they are rarely useful nowadays (because their usefullness was limited in the past and because few databases have CHECKs now).

Comment: Yes, I tried rewriting the constraints in a number of ways. I get a feeling (though I have nothing that backs that up) that Db2 stops trying once it encounters a disjunction. I'll add your constraint and the corresponding plan to my question